# Arqade/Bridge D&D campaign

Tags: discussion, community-event

A late-night conversation had me wondering what we could do for some community-building. We hit upon the idea of a D&D campaign. Right now, I just want to send some feelers out as to who would be interested in a community D&D campaign. Some key questions we'll have to answer if we want to do this are:

- **Who will DM?**
- **What system are we going to use?**
- **How are we going to D&D over the web?**
- **What's a good time for everyone?**
- **What kind of game experience are you looking for?**
  ***As group*** lets use the [Same Page Tool](http://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/) to see what kind off game you would be interested in playing.

There are probably some things I'm missing, but we can hash that out over the days to come. Add your name to the list below if you are interested.

P.S. I'm open to making this a Gaming/RPG cross-site event. We could definitely use their expertise if they're willing to give it.

Comment: We just had [a conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/arqade-rpg-brainstorming-01) on this topic in [the RPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).

Comment: I *strongly* suggest that the Same Page Tool be used as intended: in a group. If each person looks at it individually, they come to the table with demands. If everyone works on it together as a group, they create consensus.

Comment: -1 for referring to general RPG games as "D&D"!

Comment: [Roll20](http://roll20.net/) looks like a useful tool

Comment: I'd play if this were [GURPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurps)

Comment: @Sterno Eh, my "D&D group" plays all kinds of things. We still call it "D&D night". ;)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot that's the worst system  D:

Comment: I am a huge fan of both of these things and would love to participate! Buuuut I doubt I have enough clout in either community to become a participant, since most DnD games only take around 6 players.  So unless we'd be using a format that allows for a much higher volume of participation, I'm probably not going to be considered.  Still, I encourage this idea!

Comment: @Zibbobz Don't worry about having enough "clout" or recognizability. This is a community-building event, a way to bring the Arqade community together. If we get enough people, we'll try to discuss how to handle it.

Comment: @shanodin GURPS is the best! :(

Comment: @OrigamiRobot lies. Fiasco is best. Or World of Darkness. But not GURPS :O

Comment: @shanodin [Fiasco is the best, but that's a very different game](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11294/fiasco)

Comment: I vote Call of Cthulu. Because That is not dead which can eternal lie, And with strange aeons even death may die.

Answer (score 3):

This is summary of key points from [this conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/arqade-rpg-brainstorming-01).

**Proposed Formats**

- [Fate Accelerated Editions (FAE)](http://www.evilhat.com/home/fae/) <sub>[{example planning}](http://discourse.problematic.io/t/the-enchanted-forest-ethos-policies-and-pcs/3/3)<sup>*</sup></sub>
- [Roll for Shoes](http://story-games.com/forums/discussion/11348/microdungeons-i-roll-to-see-if-i-have-shoes-on/) <sub>[{session example}](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13/2013/6/27)<sup>†</sup></sub>

<sup>* Note: RPG.SE uses the pre-publication beta version of FAE, from the Kickstarter. So the rules they use are a bit different</sup>
<sup>† [Recommended starter format](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12148415#12148415)</sup>

**Getting Started**

- [The Same Page Tool](http://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/): *What kind of game experience you (as a group) want?*

**Resources for Play**

- [roll20](http://roll20.net/): *A commonly used online interface app for table top gaming*
- [RPG.SE chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/fate-game-room): *They've got [dice capability](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12148366#12148366)!*
- [Userscripts](http://userscripts.org/about/installing): *[Fudge Dice](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/170282) and [Typing Indication](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/170282)!*
- [Past play sessions on RPG.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8403/fate-game-room?tab=conversations)

**Tips/Notes**

- Dungeon World for D&D-like stuff in more of a story game framework.
- (For D&D-likes) If you have a highly variable playgroup, you might want to check out the "West Marches" style of campaign. Basically whoever's currently around goes on an adventure to reveal more of the world map, which everyone sorta shares.

**Challenges**

- Coordinating times (ppl in different regions/time zones)
- Player scaling (more players can be chaotic)

Comment: A few notes/clarifications: The play examples of FAE are mostly pre-pub because we played them before the final version came out; the more recent examples are publication-compliant. Rolld20 is really for D&D-like systems that need maps and minis; RFS and FAE only need a Google Docs file or something similar to track changing stats publicly. Also, we've got all the "standard" dice in all RPG chat rooms: d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, and d20.

Comment: I am now [terribly confused.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/160/fae)

Comment: ...my mental highlighting keeps reading over this and going "Why is everyone saying my name?!"

Comment: @FAE I was wondering why you were so popular in this discussion :P

Answer (score 2):

#### Currently Interested List

- AshleyNunn
- SaintWacko
- 5pike
- Yuki
- Murgatroid99
- Arperum
- Kevin van der Velden
- Raven Dreamer
- RedRiderX
- [El Pee Em Eff.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3129/lesspop-morefizz)
- Jason Berkan
- Macha
- MBraedley
- <s>fredley</s> [Boo the hamster](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3610/boo)
- Ender (Also extremely time dependant)
- shanodin (dependent on time zone)
- ahsteele (haven't played in years, time zone and day permitting)
- Emrakul
- Brant
- Zibbobz
- rainwalker
- Slurpee

#### Possible DMs

- Krazer
- Emrakul (deferring to other Arqade members to GM; available if needed)

#### Support Team

- [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw)

Comment: Haven't played D&D in forever (or any other tabletop RPG), but sure, I'll join in on the fun.

Comment: I've never played, but would be interested.

Comment: I am extremely interested.

Comment: @fredley Don't worry if you've never played. Sign up if you want.

Comment: @Ender Go ahead and edit your name in if you're interested.